# Storybook not working in Angular Intershop Project

Tags: angular, storybook, intershop

When I try to add storybook to an Angular Intershop Project with this command `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type angular` and then run `npm run storybook`, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR in D:/angular-intershop/intershop-pwa/src/stories/0-Welcome.stories.ts
ERROR in D:/angular-intershop/intershop-pwa/src/stories/0-Welcome.stories.ts(1,25):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular/demo'.

ERROR in D:/angular-intershop/intershop-pwa/src/stories/1-Button.stories.ts
ERROR in D:/angular-intershop/intershop-pwa/src/stories/1-Button.stories.ts(4,24):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular/demo'.
```

Do you know what is missing? Thank you

[Storybook Angular Intershop Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMkZO.png)

And I have this in my demo.d.ts file

`declare module '@storybook/angular/demo' {
  export const Button: any;
  export const Welcome: any;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get it 'working' can you try the following:

- add the `declare module '@storybook/angular/demo'` to `src/typings.d.ts`.
- add "../src/setupJest.ts" to the "exclude" array in .storybook/tsconfig.json so storybook ignores the types used there

(edit: included correct answer for excluding collision with jest types)

Answer (score 2):

just add "../src/setupJest.ts" to the "exclude" array in `.storybook/tsconfig.json`

Comment: To exclude what?

Comment: @ggb667 there is an "exclude" array